# Can I have a Form Library within a Document Library as a sub-folder?

Tags: document, form, library

I'm creating a team site and we need a Document Library titled "Safety", for safety documents. These include training PDFs and Excel Spreadsheets. However, we also have a form we fill out for incident reports. I would like a sub-folder in the Safety Document Library titled Incident Reports. This would be a Form Library keeping track of the safety incidents we need to report. I cannot find a way to embed one library within another - it will only allow either a Form Library or a Document Library and I cannot seem to achieve what I need. Has anybody had any success with this? I can't imagine this is that uncommon to fill out forms that are required to be stored in a document library, keeping everything in one main folder.

Comment: It's not possible but a Form library is a specialized document library. If you create a form library, it should serve the purpose of storing documents and forms. You will not be able to create a new document by using the new document button though. What forms do you intend to use?

Comment: You could try in a form library going into the advanced settings and enabling the management of content types and then adding the Document content type your library. This would allow for you to have both exist in the same location.

Comment: The form library with enabled content type does the trick. It allows me to populate the library with external forms (excel, pdfs) while allowing the users to create the incident report forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a library within a library. Why not make a Web Part Page and have it show the two libraries?